# removing brackets from the argument of a function like XOR

Tags: list-manipulation, boolean-computation

Xor[0,1,0] gives me the Xor of the elements 0,1 and 0 while Xor[{0,1,0}] gives me {0,1,0}. If I have a long list whose elements I want to Xor, how can I remove brackets from the argument? I tried Xor[Flatten[{0,1,0}]] but that cannot flatten it down to single elements. I also tried Xor[Row[{0,1,0},","]] but that does not work either because Mathematica does not recognize the input Row[{0,1,0},","] as 0,1,0

Comment: Try `Xor[Sequence @@ {0, 1, 0}]`.

Comment: or `Xor @@ yourlonglist`  or `Apply[Xor] @ yourlonglist`

Comment: The `Apply`s and `@@`s in other comments work best, but just to add on, you could also use `Replace[yourlist, {x__} :> Xor[x] ]`.

Comment: BTW, Is `Xor` supposed to work wit 1's and 0's? My understanding is that one should first convert to `True` and `False`. `Nor` is like that but `Xor` apparently not.

Comment: As @Gustavo notes, `Xor` is intended to be used with Booleans like `True`/`False`, The function you can use as bitwise operations with integers is a separate function, `BitXor[]`.